# CodeFile and Inherits at first line affecting Aspx

Tags: asp.net, server

I developed a simple web application on my localhost successfully. The next step is to port over to a remote server. IIS Manager has been configured and a virtual directory has been set. I have copied 2 files over,  the page VB and .aspx file.

On the top of the aspx file, I have `<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ASPWiki.aspx.vb" Inherits="ASPWiki" %>'`. When I try to run, it shows Server Error: 404 File or directory not found.

When i changed it to `<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"%>,` the page can be displayed but the asp controls cannot be bind as the mysql coding is at my vb file. Any advice on what is the issue? Could it be due to the binding i used?

The error only happened after the files were placed in the server.

Comment: What file is not found? Be specific. Include that exact error message in your question.

Comment: Hi @mason, thank you for your reply. it will display Server Error: 404 - File or directory not found.When i remove the CodeFile and Inherits section, the page is able to load.

Comment: Why did you tag this as MySQL? Simply using MySQL doesn't mean your question has anything to do with it. Please edit your question and remove tag. And show complete error message in your question, not in the comments (that's information you should include without being asked for it)

Comment: When you get the 404 error, does it change the URL?

Comment: Hi mason, that does not mean it may nothing to with it as well because i am not sure if it is due to the MySQL binding behind it.  I am trying my best on my side to debug, I am saying it politely that if you need more information from me i will be more than willing to provide if possible.

Comment: Please see my previous question. When you have the CodeFile and Inherits attributes on the page, have you tried adding some logging to see if it even reaches your Page_Load function?

Comment: Yes, the url changes to a GenericErrorPage.htm. Why will the logging help to see if it reaches the Page_load function when the file or directory cannot be found?

Comment: So it sounds like the page is loading, then encountering some exception due to your code, then hitting an error handler and getting redirected to a non-existent page, resulting in a 404. You should add logging to figure it out, though perhaps checking the Windows Event Logs would provide useful information.